# How to correctly create and use Android global variables?

Tags: android, singleton, global-variables, static-classes

I have an application whose different activities need an access to many values that could be stored in a **global variable** in order to know which views should be visible and/or enabled. It is a kind of views-visibility variable. The thing is that I want to save all those visibility values in the different attributes of this object and I want this object to stay safety alive for all the application lifecycle, then is when I came down to `global variables`.

I've read different options to do this:

1) Creating this object in the main activity using **Singleton pattern**.

2) Creating this object as an **static class** and fulfilling the values in main activity.

3) Creating this object as a calss **extending Application** in the main activity.

Then the object is supposed to be called and accessed from each activity of the application. But, **is any of these options correct and efficient to access global variables? Is it recommended to avoid using global variables?**

Thank you

Comment: You can use Sigleton Pattern to get access to Specific Object all over the application and only created once, create it in Application class and keep it synchronized.

Comment: but, is it safe? in terms of memory leaks, for instance @ArslanSheerazi

Comment: No not safe, you have to manage it byself , when to destroy the Object otherwise it will have memory leak.

Comment: You can use Dagger for these scenarios

Comment: @ArslanSheerazi what does dagger achieve that you can't do yourself :)

Comment: By our self, we have to manage all the dependencies form class and scope of objects, that become complex when your code grows. With the dagger, it is a predefined way of doing things and other can also understand our code approach easily

Comment: But, is it a good practice to use global variables?